# I am trying to use RTK query to write batch to op on firebase cloud, but nothing happen. Not even a single error message

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, rkt

This code is meant to create a mutation that allows a user to create a comment under the collection 'comments'.

```
createComment: builder.mutation({
        queryFn: async(comment: Comment, postId: string) => {
            try {
                const batch = writeBatch(firestore);

                const commentRef = doc(collection(firestore, 'comments'));
                await updateDoc(commentRef, { id: commentRef.id });

                batch.set(commentRef, comment);

                const postRef = doc(firestore, 'posts', postId);
                batch.update(postRef, { numberOfComments: increment(1) });

                await batch.commit();

                return { data: { commentRef } };
            } catch (error) {
                return { data: null };
            }
        },
        invalidatesTags: ['Comment']
    }),
```

It takes in two parameters. It then creates a write batch and sets the commentRef to the comments collection. It then updates the document with an id. The postRef is set to the firestore posts collection with the postId as an argument. The batch is then updated with an increment of 1 for numberOfComments. But nothing happens. when the function is called on the front.

```
const handleCreateComment = (comment: string, user: User, post: Post) => {
    // create comment
    const newComment: Comment = {
        postTitle: post.title!,
        createdBy: user.uid,
        creatorDisplayName: user.email!.split('@')[0],
        communityName: post.communityName!,
        content: comment,
        postId: post.id!,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp() as Timestamp,
    }
    createComment(newComment, post.id);

    setComment('');
    setComments([...comments, newComment]);
}`
```

the only error I am facing the type script warning

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)

Comment: only thing I can think of is that one of the arguments must be undefined, for some reason, might want to `console.log` them before the line where the error is being reported to verify.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I appreciate you taking the time. I refactored the function to take only arg, as the chosen data structure allowed it. so I am assuming the init failure has something to do with the error I got. I still don't get why I got the error in the first place, as I def the function to take in two args. If you can, please throw some light on that...

Comment: sorry, can't think of anything else with the info I have...